# About DateTime in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use the following code to assign date in my session:

```
Session["TransDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Now it works fine in localhost, but it gives me error when I check it on server online.
It gives me following error:

> string was not in correct format.

What is the error?

Comment: string was not in correct format. its not compatible to apply date format.

Comment: what is the date string it's trying to convert?

Comment: It could be that `txtDate.Text` is not a valid date string.

Comment: Are the two machines you tried set to different locales (OS level)?

Comment: The date string is "25-01-2014".

Comment: @MitulBirla: you need to use the `TryParseExact()` method to check the validity of the given date value, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

if your dateformat is `dd-MM-yyyy` (from your comments `The date string is "25-01-2014"`).

Try This:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
{
  string s= dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
}
else
{
 //error message invalid date
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried your code it gave me following error:"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: @MitulBirla: check the edited answer , may i know which format you are expecting from user ex: dd/MM/yyyy?